# How to implement simple Property Ammendment with Afterthought

Tags: c#, aop

I'm trying to figure out Afterthought. I want to set the variable HasChanged when any property setter is called. I have the following code

```
public class TestUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool HasChanged { get; set; }
}

public class TestUserAmmendment<T> : Amendment<T, T> where T : TestUser
{
    public TestUserAmmendment()
    {
        Properties
            .Where(p => p.PropertyInfo.CanRead
                && p.PropertyInfo.CanWrite
                && p.PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod().IsPublic
                && p.Name != "HasChanged")
            .AfterSet(instance.HasChanged = true);
    }
}
```

but I am receiving a compiler error saying `The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context`. I have copied the code from the unit tests, which I can compile and run. I'm not sure, but does anyone know how I can implement this simple aspect using Afterthought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code compiles for me.

The fluent interface was not added, I believe, until version 1.0.8, which is the most current version.  Try updating to the latest version, and if you are still having problems, I'll see if I can help further.

**Edit**
I actually did have to make one change to get it to compile the first time I tried.  I changed the `AfterSet` to:

```
.AfterSet((instance, x, y, z, a) => instance.HasChanged = true);
```

But since that wasn't really part of the question, I promptly forgot about it. :)

Comment: sorry to be so thick, but where can I get version 1.0.8? I have downloaded and compiled the code from here https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought.git and the version of the .dll still says 1.0.6.

Comment: When I do the version information in NuGet is 1.0.8, and the version information in the packages.config is 1.0.8, however, when I click on the Afterthough.dll in the References folder it says version 1.0.6.0, and still won't compile.

Comment: Weird.  I had pulled up an old project referencing Afterthought, and it worked, but when I opened a new project and re-fetched from NuGet, I also got 1.0.6 instead of 1.0.8.  Have you tried building from source?

Comment: ok, that compiles. thanks. The dll still says version 1.0.6.0, but it compiles now. Thanks!

Comment: I tried with the latest NuGet package (package version 1.1.1, assembly version 1.0.6) and it worked.  We are going to release a new package soon that should clear this up..