# Afterthought seems not working, simple code

Tags: c#, code-injection, post-build-event, aop, afterthought

I wrote simple piece of code to get involved into Afterthought, but it doesn't work and I've got no idea why. A huge part of it is taken from other SO question: [How to implement simple Property Ammendment with Afterthought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944702/how-to-implement-simple-property-ammendment-with-afterthought).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Afterthought;
namespace SecondAmendmentTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public class TestUser
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public bool HasChanged { get; set; }
            public void method()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("method");
            }
        }

        public class TestUserAmmendment<T> : Amendment<T, T> where T : TestUser
        {
            public TestUserAmmendment()
            {
                Properties
                    .AfterSet((instance, x, y, z, a) => instance.HasChanged = true);
                Methods.After(ExceptionMethod);
            }

            private object ExceptionMethod(T instance, string method, object[] parameters, object result)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestUser tu = new TestUser();
            Console.WriteLine("Has changed: " + tu.HasChanged.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Performing changes...");
            tu.Id = 5;
            tu.FirstName = "name";
            tu.LastName = "lastname";
            Console.WriteLine("Has changed: " + tu.HasChanged.ToString());
            tu.method();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles, but no changes are made into output exe file. I've configured post build event. Build output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: SecondAmendmentTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  SecondAmendmentTest -> C:\Users\Lukasz\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SecondAmendmentTest\SecondAmendmentTest\bin\Debug\SecondAmendmentTest.exe
1>  Amending SecondAmendmentTest.exe (5,559 seconds)
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And finally output from application after running:

```
C:\Users\Lukasz\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SecondAmendmentTest\SecondAmendmentTest\bin\Debug>SecondAmendmentTest.exe
Has changed: False
Performing changes...
Has changed: False
method
```

Neither HasChanged property were modified nor NotImplementedException was thrown. I'm using last sources from Git. Have you some ideas why it doesn't work?

EDIT: Here is entire solution: [SecondAmendmentTest.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1014611/SecondAmendmentTest.zip)

Comment: Have you build the correct configuration? Debug/release. Try clean solution and rebuild. Can you start in debug mode with F5?

Comment: Yes, I can run it by pressing F5. I compiled Afterthought in Debug configuration. After switching it to Release, solution doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a year later but:

To build on Willem van Ketwich's answer, there was actually a bug (oversight?) in Afterthought.NET that wasn't allowing nested types to be amended if thier parent type wasn't amended.

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought/pull/49) fixing the bug.

In addition to this fix, you still need the `[Amendment(typeof(TestUserAmmendment<>))]` on your nested class to trigger the amendment.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing two things:

- Move the TestUser and TestUserAmmendment classes out of the Program
  class so they aren't nested.
- Add the attribute `[Amendment(typeof(TestUserAmmendment<>))]` to the 
  TestUser class.

The working solution can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/willvk/home/files/SecondAmendmentTestMod.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).